# cause for mysql crash

Tags: mysql

A cron job automatically restarted my mysql database. What's the cause for the crash, or can you suggest how to resolve or monitor.

I would REALLY appreciate your input.

```
    120715 14:38:58  mysqld started
120715 14:38:58  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 411137570
120715 14:38:58 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.95'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
120715 15:14:21 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

120715 15:14:23  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120715 15:14:25  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 411166467
120715 15:14:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120715 08:14:25  mysqld ended

120715 08:14:26  mysqld started
120715  8:14:26  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 411166467
120715  8:14:26 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.95'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
121212 09:15:32  mysqld started
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
121212  9:15:58  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
121212  9:17:28  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 554145193
121212  9:17:57 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.95'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Comment: (1) There is a big jump between 120715 and 121212, Are those line numbers? (2) What happen between 8:14:26 and 9:15:32? There is no mysql crash line or shutdown line. Did the machine crashed?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened or what those numbers mean. Machine seems to be fine. app seems to be (create, update, delete, read data). Any other thoughts?

Comment: (1) Is this an in-house box or vps?  (2) How you obtain the log? (3) I would suggest nagios or collectd for monitoring mysql. (4) Is this happenning regualrly or first time?

Comment: Happened for the first time (in 2 and half years). I'm on a RackSpace cloud server with 512MB ram. Would 'crash recovery' have attempted to repair corrupted tables.. perhaps why app is now working. please advise

Comment: The mysql auto recovered itself already else it will refuse to start. Base on that log, 120715, 121212 are actually date. I suspect you have a server crash. Check your box server log, or even give Rackspace a call or email for confirmation for server reboot happen around Dec 12, 2012, 9AM, server time.

Comment: Yes, the server did crash earlier on 12/12/2012 11:22:11AM (ET). Well, really the RackSpace virtual layer went into some read-only mode. I restarted the server... but server app only became accessible after Rackspace fixed their issue. I guess that caused the initial corruption? But I restarted it.. during the RS outage

Comment: Mysql can only fix (or function correctly) itself in read-write mode. So it wasn't really fix until you restart mysql after RS lifted the read-only restrictions.

Comment: Wait, where I'm getting confused - I received an email alert this morning that my mysqld was restarted by a cron job.. so I assumed those entries related to the restart this morning. I guess not - that's for earlier in the week. Now I have to figure out why my mysqld log file doesn't show an issue or why an email was sent this AM. The email does't seem to be queued since 12/12... nor the mysql log files have entries regarding a restart.. WEIRD!!!

Comment: Maybe you can update your question or double check those email 1st.

Comment: I will just go ahead and put in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on that log, 120715, 121212 are actually server date.

On Dec 12, 2012 09:15:32 server time

```
121212 09:15:32  mysqld started
```

Mysql is started and auto recovered itself.

I suspect you have a server crash. Check your box server log, or even give Rackspace a call or email for confirmation for server reboot happen around Dec 12, 2012, 9AM, server time.

If you want some daily report of various services up and down, common choices are as follow

1. **logwatch** Usually configured to give daily report of services running on a system.
2. **Nagios + nrpe** A bit more involve in configuration but can give close to instant alert of service/daemon outage.

Comment: Yes, the server did crash that day and time.. rather Rackspace virtualization layer crashed.

Comment: I updated the answer with pointers for server monitoring.

Comment: Thank you John!! Actually, the very last line of my log file that would follow what I pasted above does show this message **'A mysqld process already exists at  Sat Dec 15 06:20:56 PST 2012'** SO, my email wasn't queue and was sent at the correct time; rather, my DB up cron job might have a bug or something... strange, except the script has been running the last few years (every 5 min). Perhaps maybe it was just a fleeting system quirk.

Comment: That is very strange, but maybe related to pid file. In general mysql will refused to start if there is one running, base on pid file lock. It is possible the file system read-only mode confused it. If possible, reboot the server to clear up things.

Comment: Yep, can't figure out why. I use ping to test the connection. Perhaps it failed or timed out.. Thanks for your other help. I should have picked up on the date and times  in the log file entries.